# PassportJS - How to get user information when user clicks a certain button?

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js, passport-local

I have a button on my website.

When a user clicks that button I want to get the users id.

I know I can do req.session.passport.user and it will get the id of the user that is currently logged in.

But what if there are multiple users logged in. How does it know which user clicked the button?

Does req.session.passport.user hold all the current users that are logged in?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

> Does req.session.passport.user hold all the current users that are
>   logged in?

**No**, only about the user making the request. How PassportJS can get information about the user is from the cookies, request headers, body, etc, which compose the session.

So `req` (from [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html), [Restify](http://restify.com/), etc.), which is short for *request*, contains information only about the user making the request to the server. Note the singular `user` in `req.session.passport.user`. It doesn't have any information about the rest of the users that are browsing your website.